# How can I simplify this statement using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

Please suppose you have the following statement stored in a `VARCHAR2`:

```
UPDATE PLUTO SET FIELD1='',FIELD2='',FIELD3='TIGER',FIELD4='',FIELD5='SCOTT';
```

I would like to write a regular expression that simplifies the previous statement, by removing all the updates setting to NULL, because they are useless (NULL is the default statement), as follows:

```
UPDATE PLUTO SET FIELD3='TIGER', FIELD5='SCOTT';
```

Could you help me?

I have never been so good with regular expressions...!!

Comment: You want to store a database query in a database?

Comment: Yes! :-)  An egg inside another egg! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(
 REGEXP_REPLACE(
  'UPDATE PLUTO SET FIELD1='''',FIELD2='''',FIELD3=''TIGER'',FIELD4='''',FIELD5=''SCOTT'',FIELD9='''';',
  '(FIELD[0-9]+=(?'''',*))','') ,
  '[, ]+;',';')
from dual
```

how's this?  it will remove all FIELD#='' (with or without final ,)

here's a regular expression cheat sheet:
http://psoug.org/snippet.htm/Regular_Expressions_Regex_Cheat_Sheet_856.htm?PHPSESSID=7238be874ab99d0731a9da64f2dbafd8
and good resource on Oracle's Regular Expression
http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions---REGEXP_REPLACE_882.htm

Comment: This will leave a trailing ",;" at the end of the line, if the last field is null.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should get you what you want, but there may be a better way, as I am not the best with regexp either:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(field, 'FIELD[0-9]+=''''[,]*', ''), '[, ]+;', ';')
```